# Is there any way to color code the data frame in Pandas? if condition match on one column then colorcode different column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, styles

I have a data frame in pandas with multiple columns in it. I have a task to color code a specific cell in column A if the condition is match in column C. 
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQSL6.png)

I have attached an example. 
I want to apply three different conditions to column C

```
 1. If Column C = poor than Column A = red color
 2. If Column C = good then Column A = Orange color
 3. If Column C = very good then Column A = Green color
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please have a look at [How To Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Help-Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) on how you should ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Styler.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply.html) with custom function with [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) for select colors by conditions:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'A':[1,3,5,7],
         'B':list('abcd'),
         'C':['poor','good','very good','unknown'],

})
print (df)
   A  B          C
0  1  a       poor
1  3  b       good
2  5  c  very good
3  7  d    unknown
```

---

```
def color(x): 
   c1 = 'background-color: red'
   c2 = 'background-color: orange'
   c3 = 'background-color: green'
   c = 'background-color: '

   m1 = x['C'] == 'poor'
   m2 = x['C'] == 'good'
   m3 = x['C'] == 'very good'

   df = pd.DataFrame(c, index=x.index, columns=x.columns)
   df['A'] = np.select([m1, m2, m3], [c1, c2, c3], default=c)
   return df

df.style.apply(color,axis=None)

#if want output in excel file
#df.style.apply(color,axis=None).to_excel('styled.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', index=False)
```